# Modify text of data member of objects inside a list

Tags: java

What's the best way of replacing space with dashes "-" inside a list that contains POJO objects?

Below is the class

```
public class State implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String stateCode;
    private String stateName;

    public State() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStateCode() {
        return this.stateCode;
    }

    public void setStateCode(String stateCode) {
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return this.stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }        
}
```

and I have the following list of State

```
List<State> stateLink
```

What is the best way of replacing spaces in stateName of all the objects in the list to dashes "-"?

Is there an elegant way of doing this with lambda expressions?

Comment: `stateName = stateName.replace (" ", "-");` - could be done in the `setter` or the `getter`

Comment: Rather then worrying about an *"elegant way"* how about figuring out "a way" and working from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
stateLink.forEach(e -> e.setStateName(e.getStateName().replaceAll("\\s+", "-")));
```

Which will use

[`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) to apply the change to each item on the list

`setStateName` to set the name attribute of each `State` object in the `List`

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace the spaces with dashes